# National Eligibility Test for Lecturer in Mathematics Question.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers, continuity

Let $f$ be a real valued differentiable function of $(0,1).$ Set $g=f'+if$, where $f'$ denotes derivatives of $f$ and $i^2=-1.$ Let $a,b\in(0,1)$ be two consecutive zeros of $f$. Which of the following statements is/are true.

$(1).$ if $g(a)>0$, then $g$ crosses the real line from upper half plane to lower half plane at $a.$

$(2).$ if $g(a)>0$, then $g$ crosses the real line from lower half plane to upper half plane at $a.$

$(3).$ if $g(a)g(b)\neq 0$, then $g(a), g(b)$ have same sign.

$(4).$ if $g(a)g(b)\neq 0$, then $g(a), g(b)$ have opposite sign.

I am trying it by taking $f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)=x^2-(a+b)x+ab$, then $g=2x-(a+b)+i(x^2+(a+b)x+ab).$ Now condition $g(a)>0$ says that $a>b.$ How this conditions will says that option $2$ is correct. In answer key options $2$ and $4$ are given correct. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: What does $g(a) > 0$ mean since $g = f' + if$ is complex?  Cheers!

Comment: If $f(a)=0$ then it’s meaningful.

Comment: Maybe you can start testing with $f(x)$ that has 2 conservative complex roots as the problem says.

Comment: Indeed it is.  Sorry to bother you! 

Comment: No I write the exact problem it’s roots are between 0 and 1.